# Is it safe to calculate SHA1 (or other) hashes of files while they're being downloaded?

Tags: hash, sha1

I would like to use hashlib in a python script to calculate the SHA1 checksum of a file periodically to see if it's fully and correctly downloaded, preferably in both Ubuntu and Windows. Is it safe to do this?

Is there a better way to do this if not?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I'm guessing its [always?] safe to calculate a hash or checksum of a file. You should avoid executing its data as code, which is often what an injection relies upon. Also see [Announcing the first SHA1 collision](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/02/announcing-first-sha1-collision.html)

Comment: Thank you. If I cannot avoid executing, say, a script I have downloaded, but am downloading it from a secure server and the checksums match is there anything else I can do to make it safe to do so?